# android intent to get point from google map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I want that my user instead of manually entering latitude and longitude ; the application should launch google maps and there the user can mark a point. I should get the coordinates of this point for further use in my application.

Answer (score 1):

There is no documented and supported means of doing this.

You are welcome to create your own activity for allowing the user to pick a point, one that embeds some form of Google Maps or another mapping engine.

Or, you can find some third-party mapping application, other than Google Maps, that documents that they support this capability.

Comment: It was possible with V1 of Google Maps but you may have just missed the cutoff date for getting an API key for that. It is possible with Osmdroid.

Comment: Yes you have missed the date, no more v1 API keys since March 18th

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/ I downloaded the code from here and I could run the app on my phone, so its the author's key(website author) right ? Is is supposed to be public ?